# unable to install the python library "requests" on windows 7

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

Encountering error while running the command

```
pip install requests
```

or

```
pip3 install requests
```

same error while installing any other python package on this system. Do I need to get any port opened on this system?

```
Collecting requests
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL
: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate
in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/requests/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL
: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate
in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/requests/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL
: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate
in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/requests/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL
: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate
in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/requests/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL
: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate
in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/requests/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/requests/: There was a problem con
firming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
 retries exceeded with url: /simple/requests/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerific
ationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self
signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from
versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming
 the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retrie
s exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1
, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certi
ficate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))) - skipping
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of firewalls installed on your network?

Comment: palo alto firewall (this is a office system)

Comment: Maybe this is the problem. Try installing anything using `pip` and see if the same error persists.

Comment: PIP didnt work either

Comment: Then try different network.. or contact the IT department with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

as suspected the issue was with the firewall. But the way i had to resolve is by finding the authorized process though which I can install libraries in my organization. 
Regards
KK

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so other people can know that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is related with a proxy, not a firewall.
anyway maybe you can ask pip to ignore the certificate issue, take a read at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)